# Is there a 90 degree angle brick?

Tags: building, angles

Is there a brick that I can use to connect LEGO plates at a 90 degree angle?

Comment: In which direction do you want to attach them?

Answer (score 10):

There are many different types. You can find them here: [Bricklink - Brick Modified](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=7)

There are also Brackets: [Bricklink - Brackets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=4)

And you could use some of these [Bricklink - Plate Modified](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=27)  or, of course, these [Bricklink - Hinges](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=22)

Comment: This answer wins in terms of teaching folks to find the answers with the tools available.

Answer (score 6):

The part# [87087 - "Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Stud on 1 Side"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87087#T=C) could work:
[image: one 87087 in orange]

But the part# [11211 - "Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Studs on 1 Side"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11211#T=C) seems better to scale up with:[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are many. I believe the classic ["Erling"/headlight brick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4070&name=Brick,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Headlight&category=%5BBrick,%20Modified%5D#T=C) (it was designed by a guy named Erling) is the oldest way, but there's also a number of bricks with studs on the side and a number of brackets.

Comment: I thought of this part too because it is so much more commonly seen than the ones I put in my answer, but the 4070 brick wouldn't work well for the OP because of the inset.  It would be hard to attach a plate to the side studs after attaching one to the top or vice versa.